# How Can I Secure the Firebase Realtime database without Authenticating (Login/Register) the user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a `Firebase Realtime` database application. in the App, users don't want to `Authenticate`.So, I make the rules as public

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

(User no need to register/login).but in the `Firebase Realtime` database section, it says as a Warning

> Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify, or delete data in your database.

So, How can Secure the data without Authenticate(Login/Register) the user?

Comment: What do you  exactly mean by "How can secure the data without setup the firebase database rules" ? How do you want to secure? What is your functional requirement? Who can read? Who can create? delete? update? ...

Comment: My application special requirement is The App user No need to do the Authentication(no register/login). so if there any way to do the security.

Comment: Which security do you want? That's the key question. Who can read? Who can create? delete? update? Everybody? Or only some specific users??

Comment: I developing a call log history saving app. which is sent the data to the realtime database using an android id. if the user once installs the app it will be working in the background. and send the data. if the admin wants to see the call logs details, he/she want to enter client android id. and can able to view the call log history of the client mobile

Comment: So I understand that anyone who installs the app shall be able to write to the database. is that correct? And what about deleting? Modifying?

Comment: if the admin once adds the client mobile android id. after that client can see the request in the home menu. if he wants to accept the admin to access his/her call log data. The client wan to approve it. so the client wants to modify and delete the request from the admin.

Comment: You need to give us more details on how you implement the mechanism described in your comment above. You probably set some flags somewhere in the database. Which ones, how, etc??

Comment: ok, thank you. I understood. I never heard about the anonymous authentication. Now I got it, Do you think anonymous authentication is the best way to do the above scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to secure data access without requiring the user to sign in with their credentials, consider [using Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). With this provider, you can sign in a user with just this single line of code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

After running this you won't know any details of the users yet. But you can now [identify the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#identify_users) in any calls to the database, and then use the information in the security rules of your database, to ensure the user only has access to the data they're authorized for.

For an example of this, see the documentation on [leveraging user information in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#leverage_user_information_in_rules), which contains this example:

> For example, your app may want to make sure users can only read and write their own data. In this scenario, you would want a match between the `auth.uid` variable and the user ID on the requested data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To learn more about that, I recommend reading the full documentation on [securing data access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).